# Search order in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

A shared object library required by my program is present in two paths under `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but only one of the two should be loaded by my program because of version compatibility issue. For example, if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `path1:path2` and the shared library `libxxx.so` is in both `path1` and `path2`, will `path1/libxxx.so` be loaded or `path2/libxxx.so` be loaded when I run the program?

Also I would appreciate it if anyone has a better solution than reordering the paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. After searching on the internet I saw some solution using `rpath` but didn't quite understand how that works.

Answer (score 2):

The directories get searched in the order they appear in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Keep in mind that the loader also looks elsewhere, not just `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which may or may not be a factor.

Since you asked for a "better solution", here are two:

### Get this broken shared library built correctly

There is a well-established mechanism and convention for versioning shared libraries so that different versions of the same shared library get loaded. A program that needs a particular version of a shared library will load the one that it needs.
In fact, it's a safe bet that you already have a bunch of different versions of multiple shared libraries installed, due to applications in your Linux distribution that need different versions of the same shared library.

This is nothing more complicated than not using the same name for incompatible versions of the same shared library. There is a well-defined convention for naming actual shared library filenames, that work together with the linker in order to make this happen (the `-soname` link option, see your linker documentation for more information).

### Don't use LD_LIBRARY_PATH

It is possible to link an executable and embed in the executable itself a pathname to search, first and foremost, for any shared libraries, either before or after `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Remove all directories from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Use the `-rpath`, with/without `--enable-new-dtags` or `--disable-new-dtags` option when linking your executable. The correct set of options depends on your specific details, and specific versions of your linker. See your linker documentation for more information. You mentioned you tried to find information on this in Google, but all that Google will do is, perhaps, refer you to the same documentation that you already have: the manual pages for the linker. That's the best source for complete information on using this or any other linker option.

The best solution depends on your specific circumstances; whether you're building the executable, and/or shared libraries, how easy/hard it is to change whatever you're building; or whether you're not building anything at all, just black boxes that need to be executed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! On the order of loading in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,, since `path2` is searched after `path1`, does it mean the library in `path2` overwrites the library in `path1`? I know the loader also looks elsewhere like `etc/ld.so.conf`, but I'm just wondering if the loader stops searching after finding an object matching the library or it keeps on searching and overwriting until it has checked all the library paths.

Comment: No, it's the other way around. The loader searches for a library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and stops as soon as it finds a directory with it.